# Change color of a particular option under select tag

Tags: html, jquery, css, select, jquery-select2

I am using select 2 https://select2.org/ and I am wondering how do I change the colour of selected option with the `value="4"`. So when `Mark as destroyed` is selected it shows in a different colour. I tried setting class and inline css directly but both did not work.

```
Not working: <option value="4" class="tx-orange">Mark as destroyed</option>

Not working: <option value="4" style="color:orange;">Mark as destroyed</option>
```

This is how the select block looks like

```
<select id="scanActionOptions" class="form-control select2">
   <option value="0">Verify</option>
   <option value="1">Mark as active</option>
   <option value="2">Mark as dispense</option>
   <option value="3">Mark as stolen</option>
   <option value="4">Mark as destroyed</option>
   <option value="5">Mark as sample</option>
   <option value="6">Mark as free sample</option>
   <option value="7">Mark as locked</option>
   <option value="8">Mark as exported</option>
   <option value="9">Mark as checkout</option>
   <option value="10">Mark as expired</option>
   <option value="11">Mark as recalled</option>
   <option value="12">Mark as withdrawn</option>
</select>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to style the select 2 replacement - not the option

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.select2').select2();
});
```

```css
/*selected css*/
.select2-container--default .select2-results__option--selected {
   color: orange;
   background:rgb(221 221 221 / 32%) !important;
}

/*hover css*/
.select2-container--default .select2-results__option--highlighted.select2-results__option--selectable {
    background-color: orange !important;
    color: white;
}

/*particular option color*/
.select2-container--default .select2-results>.select2-results__options li:nth-child(2) {
color: #fff;
background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select id="scanActionOptions" class="form-control select2">
   <option value="0">Verify</option>
   <option value="1">Mark as active</option>
   <option value="2">Mark as dispense</option>
   <option value="3">Mark as stolen</option>
   <option value="4">Mark as destroyed</option>
   <option value="5">Mark as sample</option>
   <option value="6">Mark as free sample</option>
   <option value="7">Mark as locked</option>
   <option value="8">Mark as exported</option>
   <option value="9">Mark as checkout</option>
   <option value="10">Mark as expired</option>
   <option value="11">Mark as recalled</option>
   <option value="12">Mark as withdrawn</option>
</select>
```

If you need to change selected colour apply css on ".select2-container--default .select2-results__option--selected" and change hover css then apply on ".select2-container--default .select2-results__option--highlighted.select2-results__option--selectable".
If you need colour particular option like 2nd option then you can use ".select2-container--default .select2-results>.select2-results__options li:nth-child(2)" .

Answer (score 0):

Select2 CSS seems getting the style from this rule-set

```
.select2-container--default .select2-results__option--highlighted.select2-results__option--selectable {
    background-color: #5897fb;
    color: white;
}
```

You might use li:nth-child(x) applied to the rule-set shown before. CSS aplied to the original select won't be visible.

Comment: Instead of  li:nth-child(x) Can I select based on the option value? I have the same list at different pages but the options might differ